# Edit the url in ERB to do server side scaling

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The image is rendered on my blog of website using following erb code

```
<a href="<%= article_url(article)%>">
<img src="<%= article.main_image_url%>" alt="<%= article.title%>" /</a>
```

The main image url is actually stored in cloudfront on the url 
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-dev/uploads/article/main_image/100/wonderful_image__1_.jpg

A scaled down version of size 500 X 250 pixel is stored at location
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-dev/uploads/article/main_image/100/large_wonderful_image__1_.jpg

My model of the article only saves the main image url. However, while uploading the image to s3, I do create a scaled down version of the image and add 'large_' prefix. This can be seen in the above url examples.

As of now, my erb code, renders the main image on the webpage and I need to edit this code, so that it renders the scaled down image instead. Basically, I need to edit this

```
<img src="<%= article.main_image_url%>"
```

so that erb changes
(The urls below are changed to blank client website'

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-dev/uploads/article/main_image/100/wonderful_image__1_.jpg

to this

https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mywebsite-dev/uploads/article/main_image/100/large_wonderful_image__1_.jpg

May be I need to split the article url by '/', take out the last part and add 'large_' to it.

Thanks in advance for the help. I am quite new to ROR and more into python.

Regards

Comment: look into paperclip or similar gems for the solution.

Comment: Can I make the changes by just editing the erb by using split or similar things

Comment: You can split the url and add a large but thats not a clean solution. for one how are you doing the image processing to get the new image? manually? If you use something like paperclip you can do that processing when you are uploading the image

Comment: No the new image url is uploaded automatically, I am using ckeditor. The only issue I am facing is to call the url added with "large_", so that scaled down version of image in rendered in webpage.

Comment: U need to reprocess! the images. And also you need to confirm the region for it. I was facing the same issue. Later I realised that I was using different region. I think this is region issue

Comment: No, the isseu is not with reprocessing. I just don't know how to split and add large_ in the variable in erb

Comment: there is http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html you can look into

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.It may be not a clean solution but it worked for me as of now.

```
 <img src="<%= article.main_image_url.rpartition('/').first+'/large_'+article.main_image_url.rpartition('/').last%>" alt="<%= article.title%>" />
```

Thanks to everyone